# How to let the user know which word a specific keyword is in a sentence (e.g. this is the 3rd word)

Tags: java

I'm making a chatbot, and need to be able to count the number of words in the users input before their keyword is found.

I've been able to count the total number of words in a string, but not words before my word.

The user inputs "count", activating the wordcount method. They are prompted to type a sentence, then type a keyword to find in the sentence. The program outputs what word the keyword is in the sentence (e.g. this is the 3rd word).

I've tried a for loop to go through characters and find the spaces, the if within the for loop would not activate:

for(int i = psn - 1; i >= 0; i--)

if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ' ){//if1

spaces = spaces+1;

```
private int findKeyword(String statement, String goal, int startPos) {
        String phrase = statement.trim().toLowerCase();
        goal = goal.toLowerCase();

        int psn = phrase.indexOf(goal, startPos);


        while (psn >= 0) {
            // Find the string of length 1 before and after
            // the word
            String before = " ", after = " ";
            if (psn > 0) {
                before = phrase.substring(psn - 1, psn);
                // System.out.println("If 1 at "+psn);
            }
            if (psn + goal.length() < phrase.length()) {
                after = phrase.substring(psn + goal.length(), 
                          psn + goal.length() + 1);
                System.out.println("If 2 at " + psn);
            }

            // If before and after aren't letters, we've
            // found the word
            if (((before.compareTo("a") < 0) || 
                        (before.compareTo("z") > 0)) // before is not a
                                                                                //
                    && ((after.compareTo("a") < 0) || 
 (after.compareTo("z") > 0))) {
                System.out.println("If 3 at " + psn);
                return psn;
            }
//
            // The last position didn't work, so let's find
            // the next, if there is one.
            psn = phrase.indexOf(goal, psn + 1);

        }

        return -1;
    }
```

I'm making a chatbot, and need to be able to count the number of words in the users input before their keyword is found.

I've been able to count the total number of words in a string, but not words before my word.

(e.g. your word is the 3rd word in the sentence)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want to much easier by using `String.split()`. For example:

```
String[] words = statement.split(" "); // array of words that are separated by a space
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].equals(goal))
        System.out.println("word found in "+i+" words);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be simply splitting the sentence string by the space character then getting the index of your keyword in the resultant list.

Example:

```
String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
int numberOfWordsBeforeKeyword = Arrays.asList(split).indexOf(keyword);
```